# Can I use double sided tape to install carpet on a concrete floor?

Tags: flooring, carpet

I'd like to put some indoor/outdoor carpet in a portion of my basement, however, I'd like to install it so that it's semi-permanent.  Meaning, I don't want to use glue, nor do I want to use tack strips.

I've seen some YouTube videos, and read various sources that say a double sided tape can be used. Can I use something like [Shurtape DF 642 double coated cloth tape](http://www.shurtape.com/double-coated-tapes/double-coated-cloth-tapes/df-642) to hold the carpet down?

Should I expect this method to last weeks, months, years, decades, or centuries? When it does come time to remove/replace the carpet, will I be able to remove the tape from the concrete?

The area to be carpeted, is about 10'×10'.

Since it's in a basement, there's always a chance of moisture. Though this particular basement is typically dry.

Comment: How big is the area?  And chances of it getting wet?

Comment: @DMoore I've updated the question to include the details you've requested, though I feel answers may be more useful to others of they include more general advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a type of very strong double sided tape that you can find at a carpet supply house. However, that would be harder to remove from the floor when you decide to change the carpet (it's very very strong).

If it were me, I would use a product called "spray tack" also found at carpet supply shop. Or big box stores sell a similar product by 3M, it's just spray adhesive.

The real deal carpet supply house spray is much better, but either would do the trick. Spray just the floor for a quick bond, or spray the floor and back of carpet for more secure bond. Either way it will be easy to remove when/if you decide to remove it.